# Visual studio having problems with colouring variables and error messages saying to add semicolins at the end of lines for python

Tags: python, visual-studio, intellisense

When I am opening one of my projects in the visual studio often there will be the missing on-the-go red underline error checking as I used to when I first opened the project when I make mistakes. Along with this, I get a random red and green underlining on my code like at the top where I am importing the libraries for no reason even though they are still running fine. I think the IntelliSense might be thinking I am coding in C++ as well because it keeps telling me to add a semicolon at the end of my sentences even though it is a python project, and I can't really find how to fix that because most things I search up just find solutions for VS code, but it works properly there.

```
import os
import numpy
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

print(randomNotDefinedVariable)
```

[Picture of the actual code with the colours and underlines I am getting...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQbyw.png)

The errors if they help:

[Image if the error codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5s1bs.png)

I also had problems with my libraries saying pylance couldn't resolve them at first where nothing would be coloured but that went away after I started writing some code.

I tried searching for solutions but they were more tailored to visual studio code, which I don't have this issue using it there.

Comment: Hi, have you try to remove .vs folder in your solution directory and restart visual studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copy your sample code to my .py file in VS 2022 for test and it doesn’t show any red underlining on those code. Green underlining usually represents a warning message(e.g: import unused package) that doesn’t affect compile and run .

From the red underlining error, `statements must be separated by newlines or semicolons`, it happens when you attempt to run two Python commands on the same line without properly separating them, this indicates that the code missing newlines or semicolons between statements. But from your sample code, the syntax format is correct: using newlines to separate statement. And you can also run it fine so I think it just an cache issue with intellisense.

Here’s a suggestion you can try:Closing Visual Studio and removing the .vs folder located in the solution directory and then reopen your python project.This folder has a hidden attribute. You may need to change View settings to show hidden files in File Explorer.

BTW  `add a semicolon at the end of my sentences` this syntax format works not only for C++ but also for python. But we recommend using a newline to separate statements because it is a coding convention in Python.